# Recursive function in C that returns the nth digit from the right of a given number

Tags: c, recursion

The function `int digit(int number,int position)` has to be **recursive** and return the digit of "number" in the position "position" from the right. So in my code where number=5864 and position=3 the function should return "8". Here's the main code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digit(int number,int position);

 int main (){
int number=5864, position=3, result;
result=digit(number,position);
printf("result: %d\n",result );
system("pause");

return 0;
}

int digit(int number,int position){}
```

I know that this question has already been asked but I'm really struggling to make it recursive. 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We’re not going to do your homework

Comment: @MrTux I've tried for more than i want to admit to solve it but I culdn't wrap my head around making it recursive. Now that i know the solution i realize how stupid I am. Btw this is not an homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a recursion definition, you need two things - a rule on how to move the recursion on, and a rule on how to stop the recursion. For this usecase, you can formalize these rules as follows:

- If `position` == 1, return the rightmost digit
- If `position` > 1, divide `number` by 10 and decrement position

Or, in C code:

```
int digit(int number, int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        return number % 10;
    }
    return digit(number / 10, --position);
}
```

Note: This code is a bit simplistic, and doesn't handle invalid inputs. A non-positive `position` will send this code in to an endless recursion.

Comment: What is `<ve/>` ;-)?

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so simple yet i couldn't wrap my head around it!

Comment: @CraigEstey Fat Finger Syndrome, probably. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

```
int digit(int number,int position){
        if(position==1) return number%10;
      return digit(number/10,--position);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why you have been downvoted but it works!